# Chosing appropriate TypeAdapter for changing field name in json

Tags: java, gson

I have two possible different fields in json file that exclude each other. One of them is array of strings and the second one is array of tuples. I want to read those fields and make from it object one class. For example:

```
{
    "optionA": [
        "someName",
        "randomName"
    ]
}

{
    "optionB": [
        {
            "name": "someName",
            "type": "typeA"
        },
        {
            "name": "someName",
            "type": "typeB"
        }
    ]
}
```

object read from option has fixed type. Is there any way to handle this problem in GSON?

Comment: What did you try already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to rename OptionA using field naming strategy, but I can't figure out how to check whether field is array or object.

Comment: Solved, I used SerializationName adnotation and implement JsonDeserializer.